# cat file - if exists "words" print line above "words"

Tags: bash, awk, sed, scripting

I have file with some text, e.g.,

```
######## cat file.txt
aaaa

bbbb

cccc

dddd
From CN Country

eeee

ffff
From UK Country

gggg

............
```

Now if in the file the word "Country" occurs, print only the line above this word, e.g.,

```
####### some magic command print
dddd
ffff
```

I guess that I could use for that:

- awk – like: `awk '/Country/{found=0} {if(found) print} //{found=1}' file.txt` – to no avail, and all known to me the combination with this option :/
- sed – like: `sed -n '1,/Country/p' file.txt` – as above

Can anyone help me? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '/Country/ {print previous}; {previous=$0}' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt
aaaa

bbbb

cccc

dddd
From CN Country

eeee

ffff
From UK Country

gggg

$ awk '/Country/ {print previous}; {previous=$0}' file.txt
dddd
ffff
```

Comment: jesus christ such a banality :D - thanks u @heemayl ! :)

Comment: you're welcome. FYI although POSIX says you need a `;` after an action block, you don't. No awk currently does or ever will require that since most awk scripts don't do it and so would break if it ever was required.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 'N;/\n.*Country/P;D' file
```

Use the grep-like switch `-n` and read two lines into the pattern space, printing the first if the second contains the word `Country`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep -B 1 Country foo|grep -v "Country\|--"
dddd
ffff
```

- `-B 1` *print 1 line of leading context*
- `-v` `--invert-match`
- `"Country\|--"` `\|`is escaped OR

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/Country/{x;p};x' tmp
```

**-n** -> suppress automatic printing of pattern space

**x** -> swap the pattern and hold space so that the previous line is in the pattern space buffer.

**p** -> print previous line(what was the hold space).

**;x** -> If line does not contain country, then swap hold and pattern and run again.